# Automapper 9.0 does not function ProjectsTo

Tags: c#, automapper

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
IQueryable<object> source = _myRepo.GetResult();
List<myobject> dest = mapper.ProjectTo<myobject>(source).ToList();
```

This Code Worked on previous AutoMapper but now in 9.0 that I removed `cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true` -  it crashes with `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.`

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the Automapper 9.0 Upgrade guide, you now need to explicitly configure all of your maps, this is no longer done automatically.

You can see this [Here](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-9-0-released/), check the upgrade guide for further details.